# Spliting string to array String with the name at the first position

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string to array string with all the letter as name  at beginning (sometimes the name has many words) in array string.

**Simple:**

```
car water apple 04:48 05:18 05:46 06:16 06:46 07:16 07:46 
bridge night 04:57 05:27 05:56 06:26 06:56 07:26 07:56
```

**result should looks like this:**

```
[car water apple, 04:48 05:18 05:46 06:16 06:46 07:16 07:46 ]
[bridge night, 04:57 05:27 05:56 06:26 06:56 07:26 07:56]
```

**Code:**

```
if (line.contains(":") && min_value > 0) {
            // With this regular expression I am getting it without `car water apple`
            String[] newLine = line.replaceFirst(
                    "(?m)^.*?(?=\\d+:\\d+)", "").split("\\s+");
        }
```

How can fix it?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1102891/1415929 could be useful. Maybe split the parent string by white space, test if numeric, if not then build a new string for your 0th array element. If it is numeric, process as necessary and append to array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can use:

```
String line = "car water apple 04:48 05:18 05:46 06:16 06:46 07:16 07:46\nbridge night 04:57 05:27 05:56 06:26 06:56 07:26 07:56";
List<String[]> allMatches = new ArrayList<String[]>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(.*?)\\s*((?:\\d+:\\d+\\s*)*)$")
      .matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
     allMatches.add(new String[] { m.group(1), m.group(2)});
}

for(String[] object: allMatches){
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(object));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/WWPZMc)

Output:

```
[car water apple, 04:48 05:18 05:46 06:16 06:46 07:16 07:46]
[bridge night, 04:57 05:27 05:56 06:26 06:56 07:26 07:56]
```

Comment: Does it work for you or do you need further assistance?